# Haskell Return Doesn't Match Expected

Tags: haskell, return, return-type

Could someone tell me why the following code doesn't work?

```
test :: String
test =
    do
        return ("Hi")
```

I've been struggling to make the do statement work for a while now, and I've chased it down to this problem. I know this isn't how you ought to make a constant, but this neatly sums up the problem I've been getting.

I get the following error:

```
Test.hs:5:21:
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `return', namely `("Hi")'
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return ("Hi")
In the expression: do { return ("2") }
```

**Update:** Ah I see. In my effort to abstract down to the part that was causing me the problem I just created another one. Despite that, this did inadvertently cause me to solve the problem anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GHCi gives the following:

```
:t do {return ("Hi")}
do {return ("Hi")} :: Monad m => m [Char]
```

Which means `do {return ("Hi")}` is not of type `String` a.k.a. `[Char]`, but of `Monad m => m [Char]`.

A list is a monad, so it takes care of the `Monad m` in the type but leaves [Char]; but after the list is taken away from the `String`, what's left is just `Char`, which cannot match the `[Char]`, so the error results.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. I appreciate that you gave me a method to solve further problems as well.

Comment: You are welcome; I guess you were doing something more complex than the code sample, so I gave the type in my answer. GHCi can be very handy, so I recommend you use it when confused:)

Answer (score 3):

`return` in  Haskell is not a keyword--it's just a normal function which happens to have that name. In functions, the expression is returned automatically:

```
test :: String
test = "Hi"
```

This is true even if your function take an argument:

```
double x = 2 * x
```

It seems you're really new to Haskell. You should read a nice book like ["Learn You a Haskell"](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) to get acquainted with it because it is literally *nothing* like any other language you've ever used, so your existing experience won't be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

To define a constant value (within a module) you just need

```
test :: String
test = "Hi"
```

But I guess that you are trying to do IO.

*Please*, **[Learn you a Haskell for the Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)**